# Get Entity Metadata in Spring boot and spring data jpa

Tags: spring-boot

I need to get entity Metadata like Id, column name, its length, null able etc. I am new to. Spring boot and we are using spring data jpa. Are there anu utility methods that can retrieve me list of columns and its Metadata information for the table in spring boot?

Please help me on this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java Reflection API to get all fields and read metadata information.

Comment: Using reflection API is one option. I wanted to know if there are any spring boot specific API to achieve this maybe using spring data jpa. Or accessing entity Metadata defined using annotation in the Java layer